Error in Telegraf Plugin: "invalid character "'c'" looking for beginning of value" When Parsing MQTT JSON Data
I'm new to the community, so please pardon any beginner mistakes. Here's the problem I'm experiencing:
Setup:
I have set up Mosquitto, InfluxDB, and Telegraf on my VPS. When running Telegraf, I encounter the following error:

Error in plugin: invalid character "'c'" looking for beginning of value

There's all info that might help:
MQTT Publisher Data Example:

msg send {"msg":"Hello","device_id":1234567890,"inputA":148,"inputB":-2167,"inputC":818,"inputD":488,"inputE":46,"inputF":179,"inputG":1,"inputH":1,"protocol":"tcp","date":"2024-10-12 13:41:28"}

Telegraf Output (using --test):

test,device_id=1234567890,topic=test inputA=1.48,inputB=-21.67,inputC=8.18,inputD=4.88,inputE=0.46,inputF=1.79,inputG=0.01,inputH=0.01 1728733410993721776

Terminal Output While Running telegraf.conf:
Terminal Output Image
My telegraf.conf:
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 2500 #1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 100000 #10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = true
 
[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://*****:1883"]
  topics = ["emqx/#"]
  username = "****"
  password = "****"
  client_id = "*****"
  data_format = "json"
  tag_keys = ["device_id"]
  qos = 0
[[processors.regex]]
  [[processors.regex.tags]]
    key = "topic"
    pattern = "^emqx/(.*)$"
    replacement = "${1}"
[[processors.converter]]
  [processors.converter.fields]
    float = ["inputA", "inputB", "inputC", "inputD", "inputE", "inputF", "inputG", "inputH"]
[[processors.starlark]]
  source = '''
def apply(metric):
    for field in ["inputA", "inputB", "inputC", "inputD", "inputE", "inputF", "inputG", "inputH"]:
        if field in metric.fields:
            metric.fields[field] = float(metric.fields[field]) / 100  # Remove this line to keep original values
    metric.name = metric.tags["topic"]
    return metric
'''
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://*****:8086"]
  token = "$INFLUX_TOKEN"
  organization = "hivagroup"
  bucket = "test"
  timeout = "5s"


Additional Information:

X-Influxdb-Build: OSS


X-Influxdb-Version: v2.7.10


Telegraf 1.32.0


Ubuntu VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"

I'm aiming for a specific output structure as described in this InfluxData community post:
Desired Output Format I'm Looking For
It seems the problem is with Telegraf and how it's parsing the data, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.
